# Unable to deserialise result to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have the following classes:

```
public class Countries
{
    public List<Country> countries { get; set; }
}

public class Country
    {
    public string countryName { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

Which is being read in via a HttpRequest:

[image]

But when I try to deserialise the result:

```
var Mycountries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Countries>(body);
```

But the Mycountries variable is always null.

Obviously I'm missing something obvious and I wonder if someone could help me out please?

UPDATE

Trying a different approach produces the following:

[image]

Comment: You classes are Countries and Country yet your json has Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a serialized array inside a serialized object, which is why the quotation marks are escaped by 3 backslashes. So because it is serialized 2 times (for whatever reason), you have to deserialize it 2 times; kind of like this:

```
JObject jObject = (JObject) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(body);
    
var Mycountries = new Countries();
Mycountries.contries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>>(jObject.GetValue("Data").ToString());
```

Comment: The basic problem is that the OP's JSON has "Data", vs. "Countries". I like [Qusai Sabri's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74734525/421195) suggestion to use an annotation (`[JsonProperty("Data")]`).  But your suggestion should also work.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR use the JsonProperty attribute

Add it to your Countries class:

```
[JsonProperty("Data")]
public class Countries
{
    public List<Country> countries { get; set; }
}
```

Why?

When using the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject method to deserialize a JSON string, but the property names in the JSON string do not match the property names of the target object, you should use the JsonProperty attribute to specify the correct names.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Var  Mycountries =
         JsonSerialize.Deserialize<Countries>(jsonString);
```